# Fast conversion from string to numpy.int16 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-manipulation, type-conversion

I read (int)32 bit audio `data` (given as string by previous commands) into a `numpy.int32` array with :

```
myarray = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.int32)
```

But then I want to store it in memory as `int16` (I know this will decrease the bit depth / resolution / sound quality) :

```
myarray = myarray >> 16
my_16bit_array = myarray.astype('int16')
```

**It works very well, but : is there a faster solution?** (here I use : a string buffer, 1 array in int32, 1 array in int16 ; I wanted to know if it's possible to save one step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint16)[0::2]
```

Note however, that overhead of the kind you describe here is common when working with numpy, and cannot always be avoided. If this kind of overhead isn't acceptable for your application, make sure that you plan ahead to write extension modules for the performance critical parts.

Note: it should be 0::2 or 1::2 depending on the endianness of your platform

Comment: Thank you. 
Will this be a "view" from the big numpy array ? (i.e. all the 32 bit array will stay stored in memory). 
It seems that the final `int16` array will not have contiguous data.

Comment: Yes, it will be a view. np.ascontiguousarray could be used if contiguity is required, which will make a copy. That should still be faster than a bitwise op and a cast; its only one pass over the array.

Comment: Would it be something like `np.ascontiguousarray(np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint16)[0::2])` ?
By the way, what kind of profiler tool/command would you use here for comparing speed ? (maybe you have an example?)

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct. But my 2c: profilers are a gateway drug to premature optimization. If you are worried about making an 'unnecessary' extra pass over your array, then you really shouldn't be using numpy in the first place.